# Prove that a function that satisfies $f(x^{2^{n}})=f(x)^{2^{n}}$ is constant given $f(0)=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-equations

This question follows from this link: [Entire functions such that $f(z^{2})=f(z)^{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44310/entire-functions-such-that-fz2-fz2)

If $f(0)=1$, how can you conclude that because $f(z^{2^{n}})=f(z)^{2^{n}}$ for all natural $n$, the function $f$ is constant? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you assume $f$ is entire here ?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is entire.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $f$ is entire, we can argue as follows:

Let $z$ be any complex number such that $|z| < 1$. Then we have that
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} z^{2^n} = 0,
$$
and since $f$ is continuous, we have that
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} f\left( z^{2^n} \right) = f(0) = 1.
$$

This implies that
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} f(z)^{2^n} = 1.
$$

Now if $|f(z)| < 1$, then we would have that
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} f(z)^{2^n} = 0
$$
and if $|f(z)| > 1$, we would have that
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \left|f(z)^{2^n}\right| = \infty.
$$

We see that we must have that $|f(z)| = 1$ for every $z$ in the open unit ball. But it is a well known fact that if $|f|$ is constant on some domain, then so $f$. (It follows from the Cauchy-Riemann equations, for example.) Thus we have that $f(z) = 1$ for all $z$ such that $|z| < 1$. From this it readily follows that $f$ is constant on all of $\mathbb{C}$, since the zeroes of the function $z \mapsto f(z) - 1$ have a limit point, and hence the function must be identically $0$, which implies that $f$ is identically equal to $1$.

Comment: Thank you! Just curious here- if $f$ was a function from reals to reals, would this still hold?

Comment: @JohnSmith I don't know. I will have to think about it.

Comment: @JohnSmith I believe that the answer is no. The idea for constructing a counterexample is similar to the idea in this answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1957676/146990 but requires a little bit more care.