# Functions of the form $f(x^2)=f^2(x)$

Tags: functions

What are all the functions from $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$ of the form $f(x^2)=f^2(x)$?

I have deduced the following properties :

- Set $\{x^n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ belongs to the collection.
- $f\equiv0$ and $f\equiv 1$ also belongs to the collection.
- Such $f$ should satisfy $\{f(0),f(1)\} \subset \{0,1\}.$

What more can be said ?

Comment: If $x>0$, $f(x)=f(\sqrt{x})^{2}\geq 0$. I can't seem to find much more.

Comment: Also, if $f$ and $g$ satisfy the equation, then $fg$ does too, so the set of solutions is a monoid under multiplication.

Comment: Are you looking for *continuous* functions? Then the answer is here: [Find all continuous functions from positive reals to positive reals such that $f(x)^2=f(x^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1957418/42969).

Comment: Very interesting answer! Thank you!

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the link. I would also like to know if there are discontinuous ones

Comment: Of course there are discontinuous examples.  For example, take any two such functions and define a third that agrees with the first function for $x$ algebraic and with the second function for $x$ transcendental.  This works because $x$ and $x^2$ are either both algebraic or both transcendental.

Comment: @CMonsour In fact, for each subset $\{x^{2^m}\mid m\in \Bbb Z\}\subseteq \Bbb R^+$, you can pick one such function. Then just stick them all together.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, I'm aware, but it's more Mathjax than I like to deal with in a quick comment.

Answer (score 1):

Then your $f(x)$ is anything that satisfies:

- $f(0)=0$ or $1$
- $f(1)=0$ or $1$ and $f(-1)=c(-1) f(1)$
- for $x>1$, $f(x) = a(y-\lfloor y \rfloor)^{2^{\lfloor y \rfloor}}$ and $f(-x)=c(-x)f(x)$, where $y =  \log_2(\log_2(x))$
- for $0 < x < 1$, $f(x) = b(z-\lfloor z \rfloor)^{2^{\lfloor z \rfloor}}$ and $f(-x)=c(-x) f(x)$, where $z =  \log_2(\log_2(1/x))$

for any three arbitrary functions $a:[0,1) \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ and $b:[0,1) \to \mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ and $c:\mathbb R_{\lt 0} \to \{-1,+1\}$.

So you have choices for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$, plus the three arbitrary functions $a$ and $b$ and $c$.

Comment: If you want $f(x)=x^n$ then you can choose $a(y)=2^{n2^y}$ and $b(z)=2^{-n2^z}$ and $c(-x)=(-1)^n$

Answer (score 0):

Start from defining basic functions with this property.

$$f(x)=1$$
$$f(x)=x^n$$

Now if we represent $f(x)=x^{g(x)}$, we have $x^{2g(x)}=x^{2g(x^2)}$ from where $g(x)=g(x^2)$ which gives $g(x)=const.$ if continuous.

Notice that we cannot have a polynomial (not even as a Taylor series) with more than one term. Suppose it is, we would have that all coefficient if they exist that are not different from $0$ are $1$. There is no special reason to go any further from $ax+b$.

$$(ax+b)^2=ax^2+2abx+b^2=ax^2+b$$

From here either $b=1$ and then $a=0$ or $b=0$ and $a=1$. Higher exponents lead to a very similar conclusion.

Since it cannot have any solution as Taylor polynomial, we are very restricted over the form this function can have. As a continuous function the first family $x^n$ we have described is the only valid.

Notice, however, that $g(x)=g(x^2)$ hides a lot of local solutions, where you can simply agree to have any function from any two values $a$ and $a^2$ and then extend this in both directions. You would need to treat $a>1$ and $a<1$ separately.

Comment: A continuous example not quite of the $x^n$ family is $f(x)=\max(1,|x|)$